# Combining two different date reformats

Tags: php

I'm getting a bit stuck. I have two dates in the format D-M-Y like so:

01-01-2019

I need to convert it to a very specific format for an API call which is STARTDATE/ENDDATE. This is the format:

```
2019-01-01T00:00:00.000/2019-01-02T00:00:00.000
```

I'm not great with PHP but this is my attempt at it:

```
    // variables
    $start = '01-01-2019';
    $end = '02-01-2019';

    // reformat variables 
    $start = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y',$start)->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.v');
    $end = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y',$end)->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.v');

    $result = $start . '/' . $end;
    echo ($result);
```

I can't get this to work, and I'm not even sure I should be approaching it this way. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: *I can't get this to work*. What is it you can't get to work? Is it the hours minutes and all that that is not zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the problem is the hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds that is not zero then you can just replace the letters with zeros in the format string.

```
$start = '01-01-2019';
$end = '02-01-2019';

// reformat variables 
$start = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y',$start)->format('Y-m-d\T00:00:00.000'); //notice here
$end = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y',$end)->format('Y-m-d\T00:00:00.000'); // and here

$result = $start . '/' . $end;
echo ($result);
//2019-01-01T00:00:00.000/2019-01-02T00:00:00.000
```